# Update em dados e adicionar novos

Tags: r

Estou buscando dados do IBGE (SIDRA), preciso adicionar o último dado e dar update nos 3 períodos anteriores, sem alterar ou mexer nos dados mais antigos.

Segue o código:

```
library(sidrar) 

df <- get_sidra (api = "/t/1846/n1/all/v/all/p/all/c11255/90707/d/v585%200")
#Selecionando as colunas que me interessa
df1 <- df[,c(7,10,13)]
```

Isso me retorna a série histórica do PIB

```
df1 <- Trimestre (Código)           Setores e subsetores           Valor
        199601                      PIB a preço de mercado         189323
        ...                             ...                         ...
        201903                      PIB a preço de mercado         1842700
        201904                      PIB a preço de mercado         1842740
```

E salvo este arquivo no meu computador

```
read.xlsx("df1.xlsx", sheetName = "PIB", header = TRUE)
```

Ao sair um novo dado, 202001, o IBGE revisa 3 dados anteriores (201902, 201903, 201904) e divulga o 202001,

então rodo apenas o código para buscar os 4 últimos dados, para evitar ter que buscar a série completa

```
df2 <- get_sidra (api = "/t/1846/n1/all/v/all/p/last%203/c11255/90707/d/v585%200")
```

Após ter o meu df2, quero dar update nos dados de 201902, 201903 e 201904, e adicionar os dados de 202001

Para adicionar apenas o novo dado, estava utilizando :

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("df1.xlsx")
addDataFrame(df2,getSheets(wb)$df2,  col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, startRow = nrow(read.xlsx("df1.xlsx", sheetName = "PIB"))+2)
saveWorkbook(wb,"df1.xlsx")
```

Mas essa função não me ajuda a dar update nas informações anteriores. Alguém poderia me dizer de qual maneira consigo fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há para arquivos Excel (assim como para arquivos de dados planos, como CSV) a opção de atualizar linhas específicas, apenas adicionar novas. A solução é carregar toda a planilha salva, excluir as linhas a serem atualizadas, anexar os novos dados e reescrever a planilha no arquivo.

```
# Dados de exemplo
df1 <- data.frame(Trimestre = c(201801:201804, 201901:201904), Valor = 1:8)
df2 <- data.frame(Trimestre = c(201902:201904, 202001), Valor = 11:14)

> rbind(df1[!df1$Trimestre %in% df2$Trimestre,], df2)
  Trimestre Valor
1    201801     1
2    201802     2
3    201803     3
4    201804     4
5    201901     5
6    201902    11
7    201903    12
8    201904    13
9    202001    14
```

Se por qualquer motivo precisa atualizar linhas específicas sem carregar e reescrever todo o conjunto, terá que salvá-lo em um banco de dados.

Comment: Olá, muito obrigada pela ajuda, deu certo!!! sua sugestão foi até mais simples do que estava tentando. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço uma função para atualizar diretamente no excel mas você pode construir um `data.frame` atualizado com uma função, e depois salvar ele em excel.

```r
library(readr) #só para ler as tabelas
df1 <- read_table("Trimestre_(Código)           Setores_e_subsetores           Valor
                  199601                      PIB_a...         189323
                  199602                      PIB_a...         189324
                  201902                      PIB_a...         1845626
                  201903                      PIB_a...         1842700
                  201904                      PIB_a...         1842740")

df2 <- read_table("Trimestre_(Código)           Setores_e_subsetores           Valor
                  201902                      PIB_a...         0
                  201903                      PIB_a...         1
                  201904                      PIB_a...         2
                  202001                      PIB_a...         123456")



update_ultimos_valores <- function(tabela_antiga, tabela_nova){
  coluna_codigo <- names(tabela_antiga)[1]
  indice_entradas_novas <- 1:3

  codigos_para_atualizar <- tabela_nova[[coluna_codigo]][indice_entradas_novas]

  tabela_antiga[tabela_antiga[[coluna_codigo]] %in% codigos_para_atualizar,] <- 
    tabela_nova[indice_entradas_novas,]

  tabela_atualizada <- rbind(tabela_antiga, tabela_nova[4,])
  return(tabela_atualizada)
}


df_atualizado <- update_ultimos_valores(df1, df2)

df_atualizado
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   `Trimestre_(Código)` Setores_e_subsetores  Valor
#>                  <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
#> 1               199601 PIB_a...             189323
#> 2               199602 PIB_a...             189324
#> 3               201902 PIB_a...                  0
#> 4               201903 PIB_a...                  1
#> 5               201904 PIB_a...                  2
#> 6               202001 PIB_a...             123456

#Salvar com write_xlsx ou write.xlsx do mesmo modo que df1 foi salvo
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Olá, Jorge! Obrigada pela ajuda, também consegui reproduzir aqui!